# Android, API < 14 mediarecord cause the camera brightness to dim

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder

i have a piece of code here,

```
public boolean prepareMediaRecorder(ICameraService cameraService, String path) {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    cameraService.bindRecorder(mediaRecorder);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);


    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d("ERR", "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder(cameraService);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERR", "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder(cameraService);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

when its previewing on camera the camera brightness looks normal,
but when i click record that trigger this code:

```
public void startRecordSimple(ICameraService cameraService, String path) {
        while (!prepareMediaRecorder(cameraService, path)) {
            releaseMediaRecorder(cameraService);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        mediaRecorder.start();

        isRecording = true;
    }
```

the camera brightness is become dim i have tried to change the paramters with

```
camera.getParameters().set("brightness",10);
```

and the camera still the same

what should i do to make the camera brightness become bright when record via MediaRecorder.

i am using the API 14 anyway, mostly users here using API 14 to lollipop